# Access the route in different way in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an application in nextjs. There i built the next route:

```js
 <Link
    href="colors/[type]"
    as={`colors/${type}`}
  >
    <a>click</a>
</Link>
```

This route redirect me on `/colors/red`, or `colors/blue` and so on, depending by the user. `type` here is a varible = dynamic element.

Also i have other link:

```js
 <Link href="colors">
    <a>click to colors</a>
</Link>
```

This route should redirect me on `/colors`, but when  i click i get error, because the first url `colors/red` is not equal with this type: `colors`. So i have to put something after `colors` to make things happen. 
How to solve the issue? and how to make my first route to accept the last parameter as optional.?

Comment: Can you show your 'pages/colors' folder structure?  Are you using dynamic routes?

Comment: @P.E.Joëssel, my folder structure: colors - folder and inside colors folder i have [type].js file

Comment: @P.E.Joëssel, do you know a solution?

Comment: If the /colors page is different from the /colors/[type].js you can add either an index.js in your /colors folder or create a /pages/colors.js page

Comment: Other solution is to use a catch all route : /colors/[[...type]].js

Comment: if i write `colors/[[...type]]` i get : `Error: The default export is not a React Component in page: "/colors"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223462/discussion-between-asking-and-p-e-joessel).

Comment: @P.E.Joëssel, do you know a solution?\

Comment: I've joined the discussion you created

Comment: You can use a catch all route on colors

Comment: @webdevdani, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use dynamic route ([more](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)). Start by creating a new page in your `/colors` folder named `[[...type]].js` that will catch either `/colors` or `/colors/red`. This setup will also catch route like `/colors/red/blue`.

You can retrieve the variable part of the url by using the next Router (see example below).

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from "next/link";
import {useRouter} from "next/router";

export default () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const { type } = router.query;

    return (
        <div>
            <Link href={'/'}>
                Home
            </Link>

            <Link href={'/colors/red'}>
                Red
            </Link>

            <Link href={'/colors/blue'}>
                Blue
            </Link>

            <div>
                {type ? (
                    `Type: ${type}`
                ) : (
                    'no type'
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: could you take a look:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542496/using-redux-in-next-js