# Using redux in NEXT.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-saga

In my application  on Next.Js i use redux and redux saga. I want to use ssr making http requests:

```js
export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps(async ({ store }) => {
  store.dispatch(getDataRequest());
  store.dispatch(END);
  await store.sagaTask.toPromise();
});
```

In the same time i want to get data of the above result:

```js
const selector = useSelector((s) => s);
  console.log(selector);
```

The issue is that, when i run the application i get an error:

```css
Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

I used the provider but the data doesn't appear.
 Question: How to solve the issue in my application?

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-butterfly-f7vgd?file=/pages/store/saga.js

Comment: Hello Asking, I dont't have the same error; I got store.getState is not a functiom. If I call makeStore in _app.js the error goes away, but I don't seem to have the data in the store. Can you check with this ?

Answer (score 1):

this is your _app component:

```
function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Provider store={makeStore}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

you dont need to wrap it with `Provider`. this is the only thing you need to do in `_app`.

```
export default wrapper.withRedux(App)
```

this is `getStatisProps` in your `pages/index.js`

```
export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps(async ({ store }) => {
  store.dispatch(getDataRequest());
  store.dispatch(END);
  await store.sagaTask.toPromise();
});
```

see store is already passed here. You will be accesing state via `store.getState()`. this is how it should be

```
export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps(async ({ store }) => {
      store.dispatch(getDataRequest());
      store.dispatch(END);
      await store.sagaTask.toPromise();
      const state = store.getState(); 
      return {props:{data:state}} // since you have only one reducer
    });
```

now `data` will be passed as a prop to your component. if you `console.log(props.data)` inside the component, you should be seeing your `dataReducer`